# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'

Tags: powershell

I know there are a number of similar questions on here. I've scoured them all. I've tried enclosing various parts of the code in quotes and in parentheses, a couple of solutions that worked in similar other topics. None worked and I still don't know how to correct the issue I'm facing. The problem code is identified as being in line 24 of the script, which is the line that begins **$SearchResults =** and the plus signs (+) are obviously the issue.

Any ideas? TIA!

```
# Search all mailboxes
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) {
    foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
        $searchResults = Search-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox.Identity -SearchQuery 'attachment:"' + $filename + '"' -EstimateResultOnly
        if ($searchResults.ResultItemsCount -gt 0) {
            $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Location = $mailbox.Identity
                Filename = $filename
                Count = $searchResults.ResultItemsCount
```

Comment: need parens here: `-SearchQuery ('attachment:"' + $filename + '"')` otherwise `Search-Mailbox` thinks you're trying to pass that stuff as argument of other parameters ;)

Comment: `-SearchQuery ('attachment:"' + $filename + '"')` 
or `-SearchQuery ('attachment:"{0}"' -f $filename)`

Comment: Huge thanks. The script is actually running now, albeit with an unending stream of WARNING: On July 1, 2020, blah yada yada...